# Debugging inetd issue on BusyBox

Tags: ftp, troubleshooting, busybox

I'm having issues with connecting via FTP to an embedded ARM system running BusyBox on Linux 2.6.

When I try to initiate a session, inetd correctly spawns a ftpd process, but it does not respond to any of the clients I tried (definitely not a client issue).

Connectivity is fine, I can connect via Telnet without problems.

I can't find any useful log files. How can I troubleshoot the issue?